# Unity Object Position

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, touch

I found a flaw in my code, I see that only my first ball position is monitored and when I swipe again I need to swipe from the balls start position. How can I repair this so I can swipe from where the ball is after it moved? Thank you! Code is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeUnlimited : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Rigidbody2D rbody;
    Vector2 startpos;
    Vector2 endpos;
    float power = 5f; // power of shot


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
    {    
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {                
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            LaunchBall();
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        startpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void LaunchBall()
    {
        Vector2 direction = (startpos - endpos); // swap subtraction to switch direction of launch
        rbody.AddForce(direction * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint in the `LaunchBall` method to see what are the values of `startpos` and `endpos` during second swipe? What actually happens when you swipe from a different position?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I'ld say if he swipes from another position than `OnMouseDown` is not called so the `startpos` is not updated but is still the one from the first position. Because `OnMouseDown` is only called if the pointer is over the collider while `GetMouseButtonUp` is called globally independend from the collider

Answer (score 2):

[`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) is only called if the pointer is over the collider while `GetMouseButtonUp` is called globally independend from the collider. That means you might call `LaunchBall()` with wrong coordinates because `startpos` might not be set correctly.

Just a suspicion but you might not even have a collider and `OnMouseDown` called at all but starting at `0,0,0` which is the default value for `startpos` if it is not set to another value.

So that it appears to you that you had always to start swiping at the first `startpose` but `startpose` might actually never be changed at all.

To avoid that I'ld use a simple flag `isLaunching`.

Additionaly I wouldn't use `Update` but rather [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html). Unlike `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseUp` is called even if the mouse is not over an collider so basically it does the same but without running a `Update` method repeatedly.

```c#
bool isLaunching;

 // instead of your Update
void OnMouseUp() 
{
    // makes sure you can only launch after updating startpos
    if(!isLaunching) return;

    endpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    LaunchBall();
    isLaunching = false;
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    startpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    isLaunching = true;
}
```

If nothing happens now, than you know that `OnMouseDown` isn't called at all and you might be missing a collider.